# HTML does not overtake background image

Tags: html, css, image, colors

I want to change the background of a Website from a normal color to a picture.
The CSS-Code:

```
.bg {
    opacity: 5;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% 100%;
    background-image: url('../../assets/pics/bg.jpg');
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 5;
}
```

If I write

```
<body class="bg">
```

in the HTML File, the Website is white. (If I add blur Effects, they will shown over all other elements). If I do

```
<img id="logo" src="path to img">
```

It works but I want it with CSS because its smarter :D
The image is here: (from the CSS-File)

```
../../assets/pics/bg.jpg
```

And I dont get any Errors in Chrome (in Developer tools)

Can u help me?

(If it helps, i want to edit the page "mcggehrden.de/idesk/v3" and want to set a a custom background)

Comment: Why `position:absolute` ?

Comment: @CodeRomeos Why not? (When I remove it also did not work)

Comment: `opacity: 5`? (0 is transparent. 1 is opaque.)

Comment: @ray Same... I edited the question so you can see what I want to do

Comment: Using a full width background image doesn't need `position:absolute`. Further if you are setting it in body tag it means you are setting `position:absolute` to body. It is something path related. It will be useful if you can add your directory structure as well. Also as @ray says * opacity property can take a value from 0.0 - 1.0*  [W3School](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_transparency.asp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need something like this?: [View Full Size](https://jsfiddle.net/qum5jnxw/4/embedded/result/)

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-5">
        <h1>MCG Gehrden</h1>
         <form class="login-form" action="/idesk/v3/login_check" method="post">
  <h3><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> IServ-Anmeldung</h3>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="_username" value="" placeholder="Account" required="required" autofocus="autofocus"/>
  <input class="form-control" type="password" name="_password" placeholder="Passwort" required="required" />
   <div class="checkbox">
     <label><input type="checkbox" id="remember_me" name="_remember_me" /> Angemeldet bleiben</label>
   </div>
  <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Anmelden</button>
</form>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
*{ padding: 0; margin: 0; }
body {
 color: white;
background: 
    url(https://mcggehrden.de/idesk/v3/img/logo.png) 100% 60vh no-repeat,
url(https://mcggehrden.de/idesk/v3/img/circles.png) 0px 100px no-repeat, 
    #244c7f ;          
} 
form{
    background-color: white;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When adding an img to body in css you don't have necessary to specify a class for the "body" tag. In css you can directly say body {..your styles..}. Then, insted of top, left, right and bottom say directly margin:0. Also the position absolute should not be there and an opacity of 5 cannot exist. A z-index of 5 would not do anything. My suggestion is to put a width of 100% and a height of auto or the height be specified in "px". Try this and let me know.

Comment: Like:        width: 100%;
               height: auto;

Comment: Not necessary auto, a px value for example. I don't say it will works, but in some of my cases a long time ago it worked